# Should this edit to an answer have been rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I made a good-faith edit which was rejected. The edit was to an answer from 5 years ago which instructs readers to use a particular function. Three years ago, that function was moved to a different submodule, and someone appended the new location of the function to the answer.

When I came across the question, I followed the first suggestion, which is now broken. Therefore I decided to move the correct location to the beginning of the answer, from the end (not changing the content of the answer, just the presentation):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7564497

One of the rejection reasons was:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post.

[I don't understand this since the intent of the post is unchanged.]

The other was:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read...

[The edit avoids confusion for the many future readers of the answer.]

Please may I hear your opinion about whether the edit should have been rejected.

Comment: @gnat The code in the answer was not edited.

Comment: Ben, [suggested edit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7564497) indicates that it was, eg `sm.distributions.ECDF` was changed to `sm.tools.ECDF`

Comment: @gnat If you view the rendered output, you'll see that the first and second code blocks have been switched.

Comment: it was rather risky of you to expect that reviewers will be able to recognize this

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question "When should I make edits to code?", since my suggested edit made no edits to code! Alas, I have no desire to struggle any longer with this dysfunctional bureaucracy.